# 通知機能のエラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

作成した掲載を他者に提案機能として送り付ける機能を付けたのですが、通知機能で、提案された際に通知が来るようにしたいです。
そこで下記のサイトのコメントの通知機能を参考に提案された人に通知がくるようなコードを書いているのですが、エラーが発生しました。

[Railsで通知機能を誰でも実装できるように解説する](https://qiita.com/nekojoker/items/80448944ec9aaae48d0a)
[Railsで通知機能の実装](https://qiita.com/bty__/items/2db1dd4fcd7945b980f7)
[RailsでDMが届いた際の通知機能を実装する](https://qiita.com/Shuhei_Nakada/items/430431356cdfccb1abcf)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーは恐らく通知を通知テーブル(notifications)に保存するコードの箇所(plan.rb)でエラーが起きたのだと思います。
何処がおかしいのか拝見して頂きたいです。

エラー箇所
plan.rbの通知機能箇所

```
def create_notification_suggest!(current_user, suggest_id)
        #同じ掲載に提案しているユーザーに通知を送る。（current_userと投稿ユーザーのぞく）
        temp_ids = Suggest.where(plan_id: id).where.not("user_id=? or user_id=?", current_user.id,user_id).select(:user_id).distinct
        #取得したユーザー達へ通知を作成。（user_idのみ繰り返し取得）
        temp_ids.each do |temp_id|
          save_notification_suggest!(current_user, suggest_id, temp_id['user_id'])
        end
        #掲載者へ通知を作成
        save_notification_suggest!(current_user, suggest_id, user_id)
    end
    
    def save_notification_suggest!(current_user, suggest_id, visited_id)
        notification = current_user.active_notifications.new(
          plan_id: id,
          suggest_id: comment_id,
          visited_id: visited_id,
          action: 'suggest'
        )
        if notification.visitor_id == notification.visited_id
          notification.checked = true
        end
        notification.save if notification.valid?
    end
```

表示されている
suggest_controller.rbの通知機能記述箇所

```
def create
        @suggest = current_user.suggests.build(suggest_params)
        if @suggest.save
          flash[:success] = '提案を送りました'
          # 以下通知機能の箇所
          @plan=@suggest.plan
          @plan.create_notification_suggest!(current_user, @suggest.id)
          # 以上通知機能の箇所
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          @suggests = current_user.suggests.order(id: :desc)
          flash[:danger] = '提案を送れませんでした'
          redirect_to request.referer
        end
    end
```

notifications_helper

```
module NotificationsHelper
    def notification_form(notification)
      #通知を送ってきたユーザーを取得
      @visitor = notification.visitor
      #コメントの内容を通知に表示する
      @suggest = nil
      @visitor_suggest = notification.suggest_id
      case notification.action
      when 'suggest' then
        #コメントの内容と投稿のタイトルを取得　      
        @suggest = Suggest.find_by(id: @visitor_suggest)
        @suggest_message =@suggest.message
        @suggest_title =@suggest.title
        tag.a(@visitor.name, href: user_path(@visitor)) + 'が' + tag.a("#{@suggest_title}", href: plan_path(notification.plan_id)) + 'を提案しました'
      end
    end
end
```

！追記
suggest.rbにbelongs_to :planを追記するのを忘れていましたので、追記したことにより、suggest_contorollerの@plan=@suggest.plan_idではなく、@plan=@suggest.planで取得できるようになりました。

Comment: `@plan=@suggest.plan_id`を`@plan=@suggest.plan`としたらどうなりますか？

Comment: 最初は上記のコードにしていたのですがNoMethodError in SuggestsController#create
undefined method `plan' for #<Suggest id: 12, user_id: 1, to_id: 2, title: "tssst", message: "test", created_at: "2023-05-27 23:14:15.957909000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-05-27 23:14:15.957909000 +0000", plan_id: 2>
Did you mean?
plan_idと表示されたので、plan_idにしたら@plan=@suggest.plan箇所のコードが通ったので、@plan=@suggest.plan_idにしました。

Comment: SuggestはPlanをbelongs_toにしていますか？Suggestクラスで`belongs_to :plan`とかいていますか？また、マイグレーションの`create_table :suggest do |t|`の所で`t.belongs_to :plan`と書いていますか？

Comment: >SuggestはPlanをbelongs_toにしていますか？＞＞書いていませんでした。

Comment: ＞マイグレーションのcreate_table :suggest do |t|の所でt.belongs_to :planと書いていますか？ ＞＞書いていません。to_idというカラムを作成してそこに送るplanのidを入れています。

Comment: 現在はbelongs_to :planを追記した段階で、plan.rbのdef create_notification_suggest!(current_user)箇所でエラーが起きています。エラー内容はArgumentError in SuggestsController#create
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)という内容です。

Comment: SuggestとPlanはbelongs_toの関係にしていない理由は何かあるのですか？

Comment: エラー内容が変わったというのであれば、「何をどうしたら」「どのように変わったのか」を質問に追記してください。また、これまで試したいたこと、例えば`@plan=@suggest.plan`としていたら、どうだったというのも質問に追記しておいてください。

Comment: 質問を編集させて頂きました。そもそもこの提案機能を考え付いた際に何かを参考にした訳でも無く、自分のオリジナルで作成しました。その際にはplanも関係させていたんですが、自分の知識不足のせいなのですがうまく提案する掲載を送れなくて、to_idに送りたい掲載のidを入れて、そこから提案された掲載の表示はto_idと同じplan_idを持つplan（掲載）を取得するというやり方を採用しました。うまく説明できずに申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestに関連したPlanを取得したいのであれば`@plan=@suggest.plan`とすべきですが、SuggestとPlanの[関連付け](https://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html)がちゃんとできていなかったため、メソッドひとつでPlanを取得できる状態になっていなかったと言うことです。次のいずれかを設定すると良いでしょう。

- Suggestクラスやマイグレーションで`belongs_to`を使い、関連付けを行って、`@plan=@suggest.plan`とする。
- 関連付けができない事情があれば、`@plan=Plan.find(@suggest.plan_id)`のように取得したPlanのIDでPlanを取得する。

機能の実装よりも、モデル同士の関連付けがどうなるのを整理してから、実装していくといいかと思います。ひとまず、これで「この質問での問題」は解決できるかと思います。その後に別のエラーが起きたら、それは別の問題になります。

Comment: エラーが解消されたので、上記の変更とプラスして追記の情報を書かせて頂きます。@plan.create_notification_suggest!(current_user, @suggest.id)ではなく@plan.create_notification_suggest!(current_user)に行い、渡す情報を一つにしたことで通知機能が実行され保存されました。